# pexpect command output spans and needs user interaction to press enter

Tags: python-2.7

I'm running a command which spans over the terminal width, due to which I'm not able to capture complete output, I tried increasing the terminal size using `setwinsize()`, but it didn't work.

The command runs, shows few bytes of output waits for user to press to enter, once the user presses enter the rest of the output is displayed.

I want to automate this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps insert some newlines? Or divide your output into chunks and print each chunk on a new line

Comment: Print the output, then print your prompt after it.